# Full debug option in Ionic?

Tags: android, debugging, ionic-framework, emulation

I try to emulate an ionic app on a virtual android device. The command that I use is "***ionic emulate android***" at the root of the concerning project, and I optained the following error :

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 1.933 secs

Built the following apk(s):
        C:/Ionic/Camera/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk

ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\MyKeeper_1\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.8.0_121

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
```

I tried to use different options such as **--debug** or **--stacktrace** but I never had more information on the error. However the command "***ionic run android***" works when my phone is connected.

Is there an option that will give me more information on the error?

Or if somebody knows the solution of this problem, it is also welcome. :)

Comment: have you tried ionic run --emulator

Comment: Thanks for answering. I just tried and I obtained the same error (no more information). :/

Comment: Were you able to run on emulator for at least once?

Comment: No. It could be a configuration problem, but I don't know how to fix the dependancie for the emulator (I don't even know if it is the problem). Have you got an idea ? :)